# Тема менялась вместе с системной темой

Tags: java, android, xml

У большинства программ есть выбор между Тёмной и Светлой темой. Некоторые программы не имея пункта Системная тема все равно меняются вместе с системой. Где нужно подправить код (xml) что бы тема менялась вместе с системной темой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если исключить из задачи написание за вас стилей для темы, то отловить текущий режим (темный/светлый) можно так:

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
       //process
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // process
        break; 
}
```

дальше вы на момент загрузки приложения проверяете статус и дальше используете тему которая соответствует цветности. Плюс нужно в манифесте установить прослушивание изменений данного параметра:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```

Вот есть [документация](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme) по вашему вопросу и [туториал](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-implement-dark-mode-in-android-studio/) как реализовать подобный функционал.